# OSX Ruby Gems Add to ruby path?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I am just starting to learn ruby. It seems that the default gems install path is not part of Ruby. Is this normal behavior? How can I set the default ruby path? Example:

```
[11:53:33]wuntee:/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/packetfu-1.0.0/examples$ sudo ruby arphood.rb 
Fetching the oui.txt from IEEE, it'll be a second. Avoid this with arphood.rb <filename>.
arphood.rb:30:in `require': no such file to load -- packetfu (LoadError)
    from arphood.rb:30:in `arp_everyone'
    from arphood.rb:51
```

As you can see packetfu is installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/, but ruby cant find it...

Comment: what does the command `gem environment` print out?

Comment: On a side note please check out "Ruby Version Manager": http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/ It will make your Ruby experience a lot more fun and less painful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's because you're not in the directory where packetfu.rb file lies and there's no require 'rubygems' to add the gems paths in your script

Comment: what do you mean by "and there's no require 'rubygems' to add the gems paths in your script" - again, new to ruby (1 hour into it)

Comment: oups sorry i've been a little quick :) In order to have the gems working a script must include require 'rubygems'. This will add the gems path to your ruby load path. otherwise you just have standard ruby load path